# Spring Search Lucene -- Term Spelling is Changed

Tags: java, spring, lucene

This problem is literally insane; I have been smashing my head against the wall for 3 hours trying to figure out what would cause this.

This POJO (getters and setters removed):

```
public class Author extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -590157884690722884L;
    @Id
    @DocumentId
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Expose
    private Long id;
    @Field(name = "firstName", store = Store.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, termVector = TermVector.NO)
    @Column
    @Expose
    private String firstName;
    @Field(name = "middleName", store = Store.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, termVector = TermVector.NO)
    @Column
    @Expose
    private String middleName;
    @Field(name = "lastName", store = Store.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, termVector = TermVector.NO)
    @Column
    @Expose
    private String lastName;
```

With this Bridge:

```
public class AuthorBridge implements FieldBridge {
    @Override
    public void set(String s, Object o, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        Author author = (Author) o;
        luceneOptions.addFieldToDocument(s + ".firstName", author.getFirstName(), document);
        luceneOptions.addFieldToDocument(s + ".lastName", author.getLastName(), document);
    }
}
```

On this Document POJO (getters and setters removed):

```
@Indexed
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("POEM")
public class Poem extends Item implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3631244231926795794L;
    @Field(name = SearchConstants.POEM_FORM, store = Store.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, termVector = TermVector.NO)
    @Column
    private String form; // The form of genre of the poem.
    @Embedded
    private Confirmation confirmation;
    @Field(name = SearchConstants.TEXT, store = Store.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, termVector = TermVector.YES)
    @Analyzer(definition = SearchConstants.TEXT_ANALYZER)
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private List<String> text;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "annotation_id")
    private Annotation annotation;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Version> versions;
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column
    private boolean processed;
    @Embedded
    private TopicModel topicModel;
    @Column
    private Integer pageNumber;
```

Is truncating author.lastName, ONLY with Shakespeare's name. (It changes the name to shakespear).

Why is Lucene / Spring Search doing this? There are 1,000's of other documents that this does not occur with. Only Shakespeare's name is truncated.

Here is the DB Object that is supposed to map to Shakespeare:

[image]

Comment: To see this in action:

https://acriticismlab.org/#/search <= select author, try both shakespeare and shakespar.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution is really simple. The field is passed through from the MappedSuperClass (item) and the field was being analyzed improperly.